# Facebook Pixel not sending information back?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-pixel

I'm not a dev, nor do I have any experience when it comes to coding.

I'm trying to get some help sorting out this pixel issue with my website. For some weird reason I can't very my pixel on my website.

I've added the "Facebook Pixel Helper" extension on chrome and all it says is, "This could be due to an error in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a dynamic event such as a button click."

It doesn't really make sense to me because I haven't added any dynamic events to the code so it wouldn't trigger on a "button click." It should only trigger on a page view. Yet, it's not sending information to Facebook...

I'll provide all the information I can give you!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ad block fixes everything